# How do select multiple with search relationship?

Tags: jquery, select, multiple-select-query

I need make a select multiple with checkbox like this: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/.

But I need work with select relationship like this: http://devingredients.com/2011/05/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-jquery/

I made in the first select OK is work but on change data a second select not work.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You probably just need to call `$("select").multipleSelect("refresh");` after you change the options with jquery.